# Double escaping and + symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, escaping

With .NET Core 2.1 and double escaping just the '+' sign is unescaped twice from the framework instead of once.
My code is as follow:

```
[HttpGet("article/{productCode}/movements/{movementId:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MovementGet(string productCode, int movementId)
{
productCode = WebUtility.UrlDecode(productCode);
//... rest of the code ...

}
```

I than have created a web.config in the project folder to enable the double escaping for IIS/IISExpress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A call for product code `FMB+FTR97/MB06` with double escaping would be
http://localhost:4198/api/v1/warehouse/article/FMB%252BFTR97%252FMB06/movements/1946127

The anomaly (at least for me) is the product code the fw resolves, because I receive: `FMB+FTR97%2FMB06` instead of `FMB%2BFTR97%2FMB06` and when I call WebUtility.UrlDecode(productCode) I than get `FMB FTR97/MB06` that is wrong.

At first I though was an IIS problem, but I tried the same code with ASP.NET 4.6 (with HttpUtilities.UrlDecode) and it worked as expected, I got FMB%2BFTR97%2FMB06

Am I using the web.config in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I got a reply from my question on github:
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3580

**Update**
I solved the problem. To get the correct encoding and decoding use double escaping with `Uri.EscapeDataString(productCode)` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString(productCode)`